# How to scan a QR code in live mode in Blackberry OS 5

Tags: blackberry, qr-code

Google Zxing expects an image. Can someone point me to how to make it work cleanly for live scanning (i.e. user points the device at a QR code and the scan happens; user does not have to take an image)? I've come across the following two aspects:

1. Some threads suggested to use a timer and event injection to continuously take pictures - but this approach may incur too much overhead on the device
2. Some other threads have suggested that live scanning is only possible from OS 6 and above as RIM doesn't expose those APIs in OS versions below 6 - but I'm unable to find any official statement to this effect.

Other than Zxing are any other libraries to achieve the same for BB OS 5?

Thanks in advance

Comment: zxing doesn't expect an image per se, it is a core library for scanning. It's up to the app / platform to provide a video feed, or not. Earlier version of BBOS didn't have a way to get a preview feed.

Comment: @SeanOwen - technically, afaik, zxing expects a bitmap (you can check out LuminanceSource class)! So, one could grab frames from a video and process them! Unfortunately, that's not possible OS 5 and below!

Comment: Agree. (I'm the author.) Your post seemed to suggest the library requires that source is an image file; it does not care. If you have frames from a video feed, it can be made to work via some LuminanceSource.

Comment: @SeanOwen - glad to be interacting with you :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This library allows you to do live scanning on OS5](http://aliirawan-wen.blogspot.com/2011/05/barcode-scanner-for-blackberry-os-50.html). It works as an interface to the ZXing library.

Be warned, however that on OS5 devices `FocusControl` is not fully implemented so scanning barcodes up close will be problematic. The workaround is to use `VideoControl.getSnapshot()` which is the only way to force the camera to focus.

Comment: The library works perfect @donturner! thanks! Though, I should point out that this library uses a modified version of 1st approach that i have listed - it captures screenshot periodically (every 2s) and processes it for QR code! Doesn't sound like a great approach, but I guess for OS 5 and below, there are no other options :(

Answer (score 1):

To use "live scanning" feature you need to use the Barcode API, which is a layer on top of ZXing only available in OS 6.0.

[Here](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/How-to-use-the-Barcode-API/ta-p/574569) you have the official how to on Barcode API. In 5.0, you'll have to implement a custom mechanism based on `VideoControl`. To implement a workaround, you could take snapshots periodically and try to decode them, or capture frames somehow from the video feed.
As the other answer says, in devices without autofocus, the `FocusControl` will not work. In this case I suggest you to apply some zoom instead (using `ZoomControl` class). This forces the user to move the blackberry away from the QRCode to be able to see it on the screen, thus increasing the definition of the captured image, which in turn increases the chances of detecting a barcode.

Comment: That's not strictly true, you can do "live scanning" by periodically attempting to decode the input video feed. The problem with this in OS5 is that you have no control over the focus so if the code is close to the camera you'll be decoding a fuzzy image.

Comment: And just to clarify, many OS5 devices **do** have the autofocus capability in their camera hardware, but the OS5 API does not allow it to be accessed.

Comment: @donturner You're right about the snapshots. And about the focus, I've used FocusControl on 5.0 setted to `FocusControl.AUTO`, it works if your device is autofocus capable. Never tried with an arbitrary focus level. To workaround the blurryness at short distances, you can set the zoom to max level with `ZoomControl`. Actually that's what the live scan screen in Barcode API does.

Comment: I have yet to find an OS5 device where you can change the zoom with `ZoomControl`, is there a specific sim/device where this is possible?

Comment: `zoomControl.setDigitalZoom(zoomControl.getMaxDigitalZoom());` worked for me (models were 8900 (5.0) and 9780, I think).

Comment: Tried the simulators for the 8900 and 9780 but `zoomControl.getDigitalZoomLevels()` always returns 1 and the zoom level is not zoomed in.

Comment: Camera in simulator sucks, no surprise here. I always test in real devices.

Comment: Just tested in real 9780: max digital zoom 260, num digital levels 5. You can see what's implemented and what is not here: http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Advanced-Multimedia-Supplement-API-What-s-Supported/ta-p/770659

Comment: Another test in 8900 running OS 5.0.0.461: max digital zoom 200, num digitals levels: 6; `FocusControl.setFocus(FocusControl.AUTO)` worked.

Comment: Wow, that is surprising. Having tested on a real 9700, 9500 and 9000 devices I thought the simulator accurately emulated the camera hardware. Thanks very much for enlightening me!