# QR code reading via camera in blackberry OS 5

Tags: blackberry

Blackberry OS 6 has inbuilt apis for scanning QR codes with camera, but how to achieve this in blackberry OS 5.

I tried using ZXling libraray demo project but it doesnt decode image properly.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8506715/813951

Answer (score 0):

Try [Wen's Blog method](http://aliirawan-wen.blogspot.com/2011/05/barcode-scanner-for-blackberry-os-50.html)  it works well